# Installing PHP 7 on digitalocean

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, digital-ocean

I'm trying to use PHP 7 on digitalocean but the scripts inside files won't run.

This is what I used for install:

```
sudo apt-get install php7 libapache2-mod-php7 php7-mcrypt
```

I can do php --version and I get:

```
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I check a file with `<?php echo "test"; ?>` on the browser it just shows `<?php echo "test"; ?>` not `test`. Wat do?

Comment: Which code? Have you set up the apache virtualHost?

Comment: It prints `<?php echo "test"; ?>` and yes apache2 is installed

Comment: Ah, this code =) mod-php is not enabled. Check `ls -al /etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Comment: To enable, run `sudo a2enmod php7`

Comment: and restart apache

Comment: ERROR: Module php7 does not exist!

Comment: Hmm, what's in `ls -al /etc/apache2/mods-available` then ?

Comment: No php in there either, should I post the entire list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `php7.0` not `php7`.
Just checked on DO Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 image:

```
apt-get install apache2
apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening your file directly or running inside the Apache web server folder? (example: you'll must access http://localhost/nameofthefile.php in the browser)

Does your file have the ".php" extension?

Comment: has .php extension, yeah it's in var/www/html folder and I open it on the browser with IP/test.php

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's a comment. Gain more rep and you will be able to comment

Answer (score 0):

If will most probably be your you Nginx or Apache settings?

The guide below should help you out.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04?utm_source=legacy_reroute