# How to install new library to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, putty

Hi I realised that I need a library which is available in PHP7 but I am using PHP5.3. The library is random_int, how do I go about installing this using putty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PHP 7 on digitalocean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907166/installing-php-7-on-digitalocean)

Answer (score 1):

As per the official documents state, random_int is only available for PHP 7. You will need to upgrade your current version if you want to use that function. You can use this as an alternative though: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

It has installation instructions at the bottom.